# Parallel factorial calculation of ALL elements up until a given number

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a task to write a parallel program that calculates pi (Chudnovsky formula). However, it has factorial in the calculations. So for decomposition of the task, I want to calculate the factorials before I start calculating the formula (that is, calculate all factorials, store them somewhere, and then just read them when they need to be read, instead of calculating those factorials on the spot).

I've read several questions here, but they are about the parallel calculation of a single factorial number. They aren't very helpful when I need to calculate ALL the numbers up until a given index (they are based on the parallel sum/product method). Does anyone have an idea for a good decomposition of the task?

Comment: Out of interest, what data type are you using?

Comment: Apfloat (just because i want to spare myself conversion from BigInt or stuff like that)

Comment: Note: while you can do this, each expression depends on the previous one so most of the work would be faster when performed serially.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can apply dynamic programmig. Dynamic programming is a way to solve problems in most efficient way. It’s actually avoid to compute sub problem again and again. For the factorial n you always multiply n by (n-1)! If you apply this I think the faster way to compute all factorials is serial:

```
    BigInteger current = BigInteger.ONE;
    List<BigInteger> fact = new ArrayList<>();
    fact.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        current = current.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        fact.add(current);
    }
```

Comment: The only problem I had with this solution is running out of memory in the heap for large amounts (say a few hundred thousand factorials)

Comment: @Mackiavelli I understood you still need the full array. If you don't need all the values you can keep lets say every 10th value and compute the value you need by multiplying values after it.

Comment: The OP is looking for a parallelisable approach.  It's not immediately obvious how you'd parallelise this.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth if you need to cache all the numbers no matter what you do it won't be faster than this

Answer (score -1):

You can use fork and join parallel strategy here.
Let's say you have to calculate factorial of 10. For this you'll have to multiply numbers from 2 to 10. You can divide this task till your task becomes multiplication of 2 or 3 numbers.

[image]

Here is sample code for this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask;

public class ForkTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(4);
        for (int i = 2; i < 11; i++) {
            Factorial myRecursiveAction = new Factorial(2, i);
            forkJoinPool.invoke(myRecursiveAction);
            System.out.println("i=" + i + " result=" + myRecursiveAction.getRawResult());

        }
    }
}

class Factorial extends RecursiveTask<Long> {
    private int low;
    private int high;

    public Factorial(int low, int high) {
        this.low = low;
        this.high = high;
    }

    protected Long compute() {
        if (high - low >= 2) {
            //System.out.println("Dividing number from : " + low + " - " + high);
            int mid = (high + low) / 2;
            Factorial lowerRange = new Factorial(low, mid);
            Factorial higherRange = new Factorial(mid + 1, high);
            List<Factorial> subtasks = new ArrayList<Factorial>();
            subtasks.add(lowerRange);
            subtasks.add(higherRange);

            for (Factorial subtask : subtasks) {
                subtask.fork();
            }

            long result = 1;
            for (Factorial subtask : subtasks) {
                result *= subtask.join();
            }
            return result;

        } else {
            long facto = low;
            for (int i = low + 1; i <= high; i++) {
                facto = facto * i;
            }
            //System.out.println("Multiplying number from : " + low + " - " + high + " result=" + facto);
            return facto;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I need to know all of the factorials from 1 to 10, not just the factorial of 10.